# Setting the priorites for songs in media player

Tags: android, media-player

I have list of songs like `song1` has high priority and `song2` has low priority.So every time `song1` must play before `song2` .While playing `song2`, if new list came with `song3` having low priority and `song4` with higher priority then `song2` must pause and `song4` must be played because `song4` has higher priority. After finish playing `song4`, it must resume `song2`. Is this possible, setting the priorities in `mediaplayer` object?

Comment: i dont understand which based your priority set...

Comment: I will set the every song with priority 1 or 2.1 is high priority and 2 is low priority.    currentsong.setPriority(1) or currentsong.setPriority(2)